# Why Luracast Restler is not working on a remote server as it is on a localhost?

Tags: php, restler

I copied the Luracast Restler  "Hello World" Math Class from a Localhost to a remote server but it is not running.

http://www.sensorzapp.com/SensorZapp/test/index.php/math/multiply/2/3

Probaly the index.php is not connecting to the restler.php

Can you help me?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure everything is located correctly.

1) If you copied from the examples folder I'm pretty sure the path to vendor/restler.php will be incorrect in the index.php file.

2) Also make sure the apache rewrite module is enabled. Enabled it with

```
  sudo a2enmod rewrite
  or
  editing the apache conf manually
```

3) Another thing that may be noted is that apaches AllowOverride has to be set to ALL for the
   documentroot you have set

```
AllowOverride All
```